# Magento 2 : How to create customer attribute with disabled input programmatically?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to disable this input field, It's a custom attribute.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file called `Namespace/Module/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="your_custom_attribute_code" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <disabled>true</disabled>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Replace `your_custom_attribute_code` with your read-only attribute code.**